# Get Value from object in php with 0 and 1 index

Tags: php, arrays

PHP array is following when i print it in file of $obj array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => CONNECT_TO
            [1] => Connect to 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => LANGUAGE
            [1] => Language
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => MAP
            [1] => Map
        )
)
```

How i get value of O and 1 index
My code is this

```
for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++)
             {
                $x=$obj[$i][0];
                $y= $obj[$i][1];
                   echo $x;
                   echo $y;

             }
```

is not working

Comment: $l is length and echoZ is typing mistake

Comment: Looks like `$x=$obj[$i]->{'0'};`